# How to calculate number of days in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I have a date format like 2020-01-17.I would like to calculate number of days till today date. I'm trying it's like

```
    =today() - B2
```

However it's not working.

### Edit

I changed the format to 01/17/2020 and did

```
 =today() - B2
```

The result comes as 3/23/1900.

This is wrong and I would like to see in number of days.

Comment: Change formula cell to number format .. Currently its in date format.

Comment: @Naresh Bhople Nice thinking! But more likely the format is `General`. Same result but with a twist.

Comment: @Variatus .. Yes .. I missed it. Thanks.

Comment: The displayed result of *3/23/1900* equals to a calculated result of 83. The rest is cell formatting.

Answer (score 0):

very simple
Check Out Image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rx8qf.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 2 issues that you're seeing here.

> The result comes as 3/23/1900.

1. The reason you're seeing this result as `3/23/1900` is probably because of the format of the cell. Change cell format to number and you should see your result as a number.

   1. Or you can also use the formula with a VALUE formula like so `=VALUE(today() - B2)`

> I would like to calculate number of days till today date

2. You can always use a simple subtraction of the two dates.
   You can also use the DATEDIF function and extract the difference between dates in Years, Months, Days and more. Example: `=DATEDIF(today(), B2,"D")`

[Here is the documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATEDIF-function-25dba1a4-2812-480b-84dd-8b32a451b35c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) for this DATEDIF function.

**Note**: Below is the warning from Microsoft

**Warning**: Excel provides the DATEDIF function in order to support older workbooks from Lotus 1-2-3. The DATEDIF function may calculate incorrect results under certain scenarios. Please see the known issues section of this article for further details

Answer (score 0):

You can you use the datedif fx link: https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-datedif-function

=DATEDIF(B2,TODAY(),"D")

[image]